Simulating a file that includes libtorch with gem5
I successfully built libtorch and generated the binary for the following simple function (torch::rand({2, 3});) to simulate it with gem5 in SE mode. However, the simulation takes a very long time, so I would like to ask if this is normal, and if you have any advice on how to handle this? Really thanks!!
enter image description here
I have checked the functionality of the code and the m5 function, and everything is working fine.
